# excel - Copy values from table depending on value type

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, vba

I have the following table in sheet1(Export):

```
-----------------------------
| col1 | col2 |..cN..|ctr_type|
-----------------------------
|value |value |valueN|CtrType1|
-----------------------------
|value |value |valueN|CtrType2|
-----------------------------
|value |value |valueN|CtrType3|
-----------------------------
|value |value |valueN|CtrType1|
-----------------------------
|value |value |valueN|CtrType3|
-----------------------------
|value |value |valueN|CtrType2|
-----------------------------
```

Where **ctr_type** is the name of the **sheet** in which the afferent values must be copied.

So my question is: how to copy values in their afferent sheets.

One expected output would be that all the value from the table which have CtrType1 in the column ctr_type would be copied in a existin sheet with the name CtrType1.

Thank you!

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could use something like the following. Assumes you data has headers and starts in column 1 and that there is no data to the right of the table. Otherwise, change the method for determining the last column.

I have helper functions to find the last row and column. I loop the last column to get the unique sheet names stored in a dictionary and at the same time add the range to the left of the sheet name into the dictionary. If the sheet name exists as a key in the dictionary, I use Union to add the current range to the left to the existing rows found for this sheet name.

I re-loop the dictionary using the sheet name keys to write the values to the appropriate sheets. You should add error handling e.g. what if sheet is not present?

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub WriteValues()
    Dim rng As Range, ws As Worksheet, loopRange As Range, sheetDict As Object
    Set ws = ActiveSheet: Set sheetDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With ws
        Set loopRange = Range(.Cells(2, GetLastColumn(ws, 1)), .Cells(GetLastRow(ws, 1), GetLastColumn(ws, 1)))
        For Each rng In loopRange
            If Not sheetDict.Exists(rng.Value) Then
                Dim tempRange As Range
                Set tempRange = .Range(.Cells(rng.Row, 1), .Cells(rng.Row, GetLastColumn(ws, 1) - 1))
                sheetDict.Add rng.Value, tempRange.Address
            Else
                Set tempRange = Union(.Range(sheetDict(rng.Value)), .Range(.Cells(rng.Row, 1), .Cells(rng.Row, GetLastColumn(ws, 1) - 1)))
                sheetDict(rng.Value) = tempRange.Address
            End If
        Next rng
        For Each rng In loopRange
            Set tempRange = .Range(sheetDict(rng.Value))
            If Not tempRange Is Nothing Then
                tempRange.Copy Worksheets(rng.Value).Range("A" & GetLastRow(Worksheets(rng.Value), 1))
            End If
        Next rng
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetLastColumn(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal rowNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastColumn = .Cells(rowNumber, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
End Function

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! There is no need to handle the "sheet not existing" problem because is have made a script that creates sheets based on ctr_type